# Django admin: Change selected box of related fields to autocomplete

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-admin, foreign-keys

We have some models that are have a user as a foreign key. But with about 25000 users in our system, it's a bit daunting to find the one we need.

Is there a solution out there that's better than the select box?  Maybe an autocomplete so we can start typing the user name / address?  Or just a search box?  When switching the related user for these objects, it's getting harder and harder with 25000 unsorted users.

Even just setting it to sort the users by username would be helpful.

Comment: This seems to be hot: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had this problem and my conclusion was to use an autocomplete field instead. It works pretty well in most cases. The only problem is when you have a lot of entries that are mostly the same. For example, in your case, if you type *Robert* for the name and there's a few hundred *Robert* entries in the list...

**UPDATE**

As mentions in shuckc's answer, Django 2.0+ admin as now [autocomplete built in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields).

**For older Django or to use outside of the admin (old answer)**

There are many apps that add autocomplete to the Django admin:

- [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io)
- [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) ([ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/admin/__init__.py))
- [django-autocomplete](http://code.google.com/p/django-autocomplete/) (on google code)
- [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects)
- [django-admin-autocomplete](https://bitbucket.org/tymofiy/django-admin-autocomplete)
- [django-autocomplete](https://bitbucket.org/tyrion/django-autocomplete) (tyrion)

My preferred one is the last one. It's well written, it can be used with the admin and outside of the admin, it works with ManyToManyFields, ForeignKeyFields, CharFields, etc.

I did a [fork](https://bitbucket.org/etienned/django-autocomplete/overview) of this project for my client that adds some niceties like a lookup (loupe) button like the `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget`.

Answer (score 32):

Django 2.0 admin has [autocomplete built in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields), just set the `autocomplete_fields` field on the `ModelAdmin` class. e.g.

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['date_created']
    search_fields = ['question_text']

class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['question']
```

Comment: I was wondering if anyone knew if the admin autocomplete is available to user in our own views if the code is already built into Django 2. If not, what are people using.

Comment: It would be great to discover a way to use admin autocomplete outside of admin. Could someone point to a possible use case?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest out-of-the-box solution is to add the field to your `ModelAdmin`'s [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) -- then you'll get a pop-up window in which you can use the built-in searching/filtering and pagination control's to find and select the object you're after.

If you really want autocomplete, the other answers give a you reasonable starting point.

Comment: If you are using the old Django version, which does not have well supported autocomplete packages - in that case, it should be your favorite answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`ForeignKeyRawIdWidget`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L126) from `django.contrib.admin.widgets`. It renders FK relations as an input with a small button along-side which presents a searchable pop up.

Answer (score 0):

[There is an app for that](http://code.google.com/p/django-autocomplete/) (django-autocomplete).